# ASP.NET MVC Issues - Namespace not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

Basically any place that a MVC resource is needed in my application, it is being listed in the error list (234 errors, almost every single one is the exact same error).

I am able to get intellisense when I type `System.Web.Mvc.`, and add a `Controller`, but after building, the line which the `Controller` was added to shows in blue font, but it is underlined.

I have literally tried so many solutions from Stack, most often discussed is:

- Remove reference to `System.Web.Mvc` and re-add. Set `copy local` to true.

**Screenshot of subset of errors below.**

[image: Errors]

**I am surprised that it is being flagged here, when it is recognizing `Controller` in the inheritance.**

[image: Class declaration]

**Here too**

[image]

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? can you post that error?

Comment: @MithunPattankar ver. 4, error posted in OP.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade this project?

Comment: @ErikPhilips in short, yes. I have a working version of this solution, but in order to use DevExpress MVC functionality, I needed to recreate the WebApplication using *their* WebApplication, not the default WebApplication.

Comment: Then most likely the problem is that the project is targeting a newer version of .Net and the MVC dlls the project are references are targeting an older .Net version causing it to not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is never the nice answer... I recreated the solution, and very carefully chose all of my options when configuring. I built to the browser after all changes, and so far everything is working out.